# Local service in Angular doesn't accept data rather then string format

Tags: angular, service, arguments

I have this local service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: any) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

And then, when I call it's method in a component, like this

```
submitReview(){

  let credentials = {
  author: this.userName,
  review: this.userReview.value,
  movie: this.id
}
this.localService.changeMessage(credentials)
}
```

I get this error `Argument of type '{ author: string; review: any; movie: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`
I dont understand since the message type is set to any...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does localService connect/interact with browser localStorage?

Comment: Well i dont know, at this point the app is quite large and somehere there is use of localsotorage...Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not clear but likely localService interacts with localStorage somewhere in your application. localStorage gets/sets via type string. Try stringify on your payload:

```
this.localService.changeMessage(JSON.stringify(credentials))
```

Or in localService stringify before doing next:

```
this.messageSource.next(JSON.stringify(message))
```

Or finally find where localStorage is actually interacted with in your application and stringify it there. Maybe it’s not localStorage but it could be something similar that expects a string payload. Either way try doing stringify on the payload.